# How to grab a String BEFORE a certain word

Tags: php

I want to grab a string BEFORE a certain word. I know how to grab after but not before.

I know the code to grab after a certain word is:

```
GetStringBetween(getURL("url),"startstring", 'stopstring');
```

But what if I want to grab before a certain string? My thing in question is :
    `mpegURL|m3u8|172d45823df011328d1450903533c9e6|org|play|iZ7XfsOZq8SgEGdeG1RasA|1565987357|videoserver2`

The `565987357` part changes, and so does the play ID, so I can't for example tell it to start grabbing from the A| part because it won't always be A|. So I need PHP code that will grab everything before the `|video` and stop at the `|` that starts the changing number, sort of like a reverse `getstringbetween` in a way... Thanks for all your advice.

Comment: Why not use a regex?

Comment: im not familer with Reg im new to the PHP world do you have an example?

Comment: Just to confirm - what is the expected output from the sample string that you give.

Comment: i want a code that would grab the number between | and |Video ex the `565987357` theres no like start string to tell it to start to grab it

Comment: Just use explode in php. Regex looks more expensive to me here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of **|** delimiters in your string is constant you can do:

```
$string = 'mpegURL|m3u8|172d45823df011328d1450903533c9e6|org|play|iZ7XfsOZq8SgEGdeG1RasA|1565987357|videoserver2';

$stringParts = explode('|', $string);
$numbers = $stringParts[6];
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a delimited file so I would use `str_getcsv` and define the delimiter `|`.

```
$pipes = str_getcsv('mpegURL|m3u8|172d45823df011328d1450903533c9e6|org|play|iZ7XfsOZq8SgEGdeG1RasA|1565987357|videoserver2', '|');
echo $pipes[6];
```